To remove a nth node from the end of a linked list i have written this program
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     struct ListNode *next;
 * };
 */

int isfound(struct ListNode* head, int i );

int isfound(struct ListNode* head, int i )
{
    while(i--)
    {
        if(head == NULL) return 0;
        head = head->next;
    }
    head = head->next ;
    return (head == NULL)? 1 : 0 ;
}

struct ListNode* removeNthFromEnd(struct ListNode* head, int n) {
    
    struct ListNode* temp = head ;
    struct ListNode* prev = NULL ;
    if(isfound(head,n+1))
    {
        head = NULL;
        return head;
    }
    while( temp != NULL)
    {
        
        if(isfound(temp,n))
        {
            temp->next = temp->next->next;
            return head;
        }
        prev = temp ;
        temp = temp->next; 
    }

    return head;

}

it should work right? i dont know why NULL pointer exception is coming . It can point to NULL too i think.

Edit the question to provide a [mre].

If you're hitting a "NULL pointer exception" then it's obviously not working.  What have you learned debugging your program?

You have two consecutive head = head->next; when the while loop terminates. If the 1st statement puts NULL in head, the 2nd will give the exception.

Thanks everyone for taking the time to answer
